# Build a timeseries dataframe in pandas using a start date / end date

Tags: pandas

I am attempting to complete a cohort analysis in `pandas`.  I would like to be able to look at activity of the user at Month 1, Month 2, Month n and group that by when the user signed up.  You could use `groupby` to accomplish this, but if the user is inactive during a particular month, then they would not actually show in the data for the month.

Ideally, here is the `dataframe` I am trying to build:

```
| UserID | SignUpDate | VisitMonth | Visits |
|--------|------------|------------|--------|
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-03    | 2      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-04    | 1      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-05    | 0      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-06    | 0      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-07    | 0      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-08    | 0      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-09    | 0      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-10    | 1      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-11    | 0      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2014-12    | 0      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2015-01    | 2      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2015-02    | 1      |
| 1      | 2014-03    | 2015-03    | 0      |
| 2      | 2015-01    | 2015-01    | 2      |
| 2      | 2015-01    | 2015-02    | 0      |
| 2      | 2015-01    | 2015-03    | 2      |
```

#### Here is some sample data:

```
#Sample of users
users = [{'UserID': 'U1', 'SignUpDate': '2014-03-15'}, {'UserID': 'U2', 'SignUpDate': '2015-01-10'}]

#Create dataframe with users
usersDF = pd.DataFrame(data=users)

#Convert SignUpDate from Object to date
usersDF['SignUpDate'] = pd.to_datetime(usersDF['SignUpDate'])

#Add new column to build the month-only 
usersDF['SignUpMonth'] = usersDF['SignUpDate'].dt.to_period('M')

#Sample of visits
visits =[{'UserID': 'U1', 'VisitDate': '2014-03-15'}, {'UserID': 'U1', 'VisitDate': '2014-03-28'}, {'UserID': 'U1', 'VisitDate': '2014-04-10'}, {'UserID': 'U1', 'VisitDate': '2014-10-28'}, {'UserID': 'U1', 'VisitDate': '2015-01-02'}, {'UserID': 'U2', 'VisitDate': '2015-01-10'}, {'UserID': 'U2', 'VisitDate': '2015-01-11'}, {'UserID': 'U1', 'VisitDate': '2014-01-20'}, {'UserID': 'U1', 'VisitDate': '2014-02-15'}, {'UserID': 'U2', 'VisitDate': '2015-03-01'}, {'UserID': 'U2', 'VisitDate': '2015-03-18'}]

#Create dataframe of visits
visitDF = pd.DataFrame(data=visits)

#Convert VisitDate from object to date
visitDF['VisitDate'] = pd.to_datetime(visitDF['VisitDate'])

#Add new column to build the month-only 
visitDF['VisitMonth'] = visitDF['VisitDate'].dt.to_period('M')

#Group by to get the visits by user by month
visits_grouped = visitDF.groupby(['UserID', 'VisitMonth']).agg(['count'])

#Remove the index on UserID so can `merge`
visits_grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)

#Grouped by dataframe
cohortDF = visits_grouped.merge(usersDF[['UserID', 'SignUpMonth']], on='UserID', how='left')
```

This groupby/merge only builds a dataframe where there are visits, where as I want to be able to aggregate other fields regardless of if there is a visit or not.

#### Grouped DF output:

```
  UserID VisitMonth VisitDate
                        count
0     U1    2014-01         1
1     U1    2014-02         1
2     U1    2014-03         2
3     U1    2014-04         1
4     U1    2014-10         1
5     U1    2015-01         1
6     U2    2015-01         2
7     U2    2015-03         2
```

#### How I tried to solve this

I figured a `for loop` would work for this, but I am having trouble breaking apart the DFs / datatypes of the DF.  Here is some rough (not working at all) code of how I thought about this:

*Note: THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK*

```
for user in range(0, len(usersDF)):
    TheUserID = usersDF['UserID'][user]
    TheSignUpMonth = usersDF['SignUpMonth'][user]
    AnalysisMonth = pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime(2015,03,31)).to_period('M')
    numperiods = AnalysisMonth - TheSignUpMonth
    months = pd.date_range(TheSignUpMonth, periods=numperiods, freq='M')
    for month in months:
        df.append([TheUserID, TheSignUpMonth, month])
```

There are a few issues with this approach.

1. Using a for loop doesn't seem very 'panda-ish' to me.
2. the numperiods part doesn't work.  I know there are ways with `datetime` to determine the number of days/months/etc between two dates, but trying to calculate the difference between the month series does not work.
3. Incrementally building a dataframe (per UserID, per month) has given me a bit of a problem since we're dealing with strings and panda timeseries objects.

How could I build the dataframe I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using you example `dataframe`:

add a helper column to aggregate (needed as all other columns are used in the indices of the pivot table)

```
visitDF['counter'] = 1
```

then create a pivot table so the `VisitDate` column is in an index by itself, and the other dimensions are in the other.

```
df =pd.pivot_table(visitDF,index = 'VisitDate', columns=['VisitMonth','UserID'],\
               values='counter', aggfunc='sum').
```

Then resample the index to day. This creates `NAN` values for days with no values

```
df =df.resample('D',how='sum')
```

Then unstack the frame, reset the index and fill `NAN` with 0 to get the frame you need.

```
df.unstack().reset_index().fillna(0)
```